# IF test returning too many arguments for path comparison

Tags: bash

If below should return true but it actually fails with an error reporting too many arguments when executed in bash shell. I think I followed all the guidelines with double quotes and can't figure out why it is failing for the life of me...  Any ideas?

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# These are the values in the environment
#echo ">"$PS_APP_HOME"<"  => >/app/psoft/app_85909<
#echo ">"PS_CUST_HOME"<"  => >/app/psoft/cust_85909<
#echo ">"$(pwd)"<"        => >/app/psoft/app_85909<

if [ "$(pwd)" != "$PS_APP_HOME" ] -o [ "$(pwd)" != "$PS_CUST_HOME" ]
```

Comment: FYI you don't have to run `pwd` to get the current dir in bash.  bash automatically keeps the `$PWD` variable up-to-date with the current directory.

Comment: One important thing the answers don't emphasize (yet) is: `[` is a command, *nothing more.* `[` requires `]` as the last argument, so it *looks* like some special syntax, but it's not. `[` is neither a part of the syntax of `if`, nor a keyword in the shell that makes the shell parse things differently. `[` usually is a builtin, but it still behaves like a command. `[` can be `/usr/bin/[` or so. OTOH [`[[` is special in Bash](https://superuser.com/a/1708896/432690).

Comment: You're using the wrong logical operator, it should be `AND`, not `OR`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true

Comment: I don't believe I am using the wrong logical operator.  It is intended to be an or as in:

Comment: Barmar, I think you are right. My logic would generate a fail message even if one of the locations is correct, which was what was being checked for.  Thanks for the pointer!
However, don't quite get why that would trigger too many arguments error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> [ "$(pwd)" != "$PS_APP_HOME" ] -o [ "$(pwd)" != "$PS_CUST_HOME" ]
> ```

calls the `[` command with the following as arguments:

1. output of `pwd`¹,
2. `!=`,
3. the contents of the `PS_APP_HOME` variable,
4. `]`,
5. `-o`,
6. `[`,
7. the output of another invocation of `pwd`,
8. `!=`,
9. the contents of the `PS_CUST_HOME` variable, and
10. `]`.

The `]` is meant to be the last argument, so when `[` sees `-o` after the first `]`, it is confused.

`[` has a deprecated `-o` operator for *OR*, but that's meant to be used as `[ some-condition -o some-other-condition ]`. It should however not be used as it makes for unreliable test expressions.

Here, using *OR* also doesn't make sense. The current working directory cannot be at the same time something (`$PS_APP_HOME`) and something else (`$PS_CUSTOM_HOME`), so at least one of `"$(pwd)" != "$PS_APP_HOME"` or `"$(pwd)" != "$PS_CUST_HOME"` is going to be true. Presumably you meant *AND* instead of *OR*. So:

- with standard syntax:

  ```
  if [ "$PWD" != "$PS_APP_HOME" ] && [ "$PWD" != "$PS_CUST_HOME" ]; then
    echo current directory is neither the APP nor CUST home
  fi
  ```

  (where we run a second `[` command if the first one was successful using the `&&` *shell* (not `[`) operator).
- Korn-like syntax:

  ```
  if [[ $PWD != "$PS_APP_HOME" && $PWD != "$PS_CUST_HOME" ]]; then
    echo current directory is neither the APP nor CUST home
  fi
  ```

  or

  ```
  if [[ ! ($PWD = "$PS_APP_HOME" || $PWD = "$PS_CUST_HOME") ]]; then
    echo current directory is neither the APP nor CUST home
  fi
  ```

  where `[[...]]` is a special construct with its own *conditional expression* micro-language code inside which also has some `&&` (and) / `||` (or), `!` (not) boolean operators.

Though you could also use `case`:

```
case $PWD in
  ("$PS_APP_HOME" | "$PS_CUST_HOME") ;;
  (*) echo current directory is neither the APP nor CUST home
esac
```

`$PWD` is like `$(pwd)` except it's more efficient as it doesn't need to fork another process and get its output through a pipe and means it still works if the path of the current working directory ends in newline characters.²

Beware the double quotes above are important, I've only put them where they are strictly necessary (to prevent split+glob in the arguments of `[` and to prevent variable values to be taken as a pattern in the argument the `!=` / `=` operators of the `[[...]]` construct or `case`), though having *all* expansions quoted would not harm.

Instead of doing lexical comparisons, also note that ksh/bash/zsh's `[[....]]` and most `[` implementations including the `[` builtin of `bash` support a `-ef` operator, to check whether two files are the same (after symlink resolution), so you could use that instead of `=`:

```
if [[ ! (. -ef $PS_APP_HOME || . -ef $PS_CUST_HOME) ]]; then
  echo current directory is neither the APP nor CUST home
fi
```

Or for `sh` (most `sh`s):

```
if [ ! . -ef "$PS_APP_HOME" ] && [ ! . -ef "$PS_CUST_HOME" ]; then
  echo current directory is neither the APP nor CUST home
fi
```

Here also using `.` which unlike `$PWD` or `$(pwd)` is guaranteed to refer to the current working directory.

That way if `$PWD` is `/opt/app` or `/some/link/to/app` and `$PS_APP_HOME` is `/opt/./app` or `/opt/foo/../app` or `/opt//app` for instance, that will still work.

---

<sup>¹ stripped of all trailing newline characters, so maybe not the current working directory.</sup>

<sup>² in some shells, `$PWD` might give you stale information though if the current working directory has been renamed under your feet. But then again, that's also true of `pwd` in some shells which just output the value of `$PWD` and only update it upon `cd`/`pushd`/`popd`.</sup>

Comment: Simply `cd` to the desired directory and avoid all this. If you're not there already, you have to do it anyway. If you are already there, no error is returned.

Comment: I prefer the user to be in one of the target directories to confirm intent.  if they are in either one of the targets in question that may not be the intended target.

Comment: I ended up settling with

if [ "$PWD" != "$PS_APP_HOME" && "$PWD" != "$PS_CUST_HOME" ] 

which works just fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
if [ "$(pwd)" != "$PS_APP_HOME" ] -o [ "$(pwd)" != "$PS_CUST_HOME" ]
```

This is syntactically incorrect, which is why you get the error you report.

If you want to do this as one test, it should be:

```
if [ "$(pwd)" != "$PS_APP_HOME" -o "$(pwd)" != "$PS_CUST_HOME" ]
```

Or, if you want to keep the expressions completely separate and have `bash` handle the logical "or" for you:

```
if [ "$(pwd)" != "$PS_APP_HOME" ] || [ "$(pwd)" != "$PS_CUST_HOME" ]
```

Comment: The second form with `||` is generally considered preferable.